# command history

Tags: grep, find, redirect, history, tail

Which is the most correct answer for this question: Write a one-line command that searches the last 50 commands that have been used for the term "find", and saves the result in history.txt

```
Answer 1: history | grep "find" | tail -n 50 > history.txt
Answer 2: history | tail -n 50 | grep 'find' >history.txt
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question - please share your attempt to solve it

Comment: my Answer was: history | grep "find" | tail -n 50 > history.txt

Comment: but teacher gives: history | tail -n 50 | grep 'find' >history.txt

Comment: So... does `history | grep "find"` search the last 50 commands? or does it search all the commands?

Comment: it will search for all the "find" commands and tail -n 50 will give the last 50 "find" commands (if there are more than 50 commands).

Comment: Right - which is not what the question asks for

Comment: The teacher is correct, but the question seems poorly worded. "*...the last 50 commands that have been used for the term 'find'*" (Answer 2) is different from "*...the last 50 commands that used the term 'find'*" (Answer 1). I am a native english speaker with years of experience parsing out obscure clauses, and it still took me two reads to puzzle out what the question was asking. A clearer phrasing would be more along the lines of "*...occurrences of the term 'find' among the 50 most recent commands*"

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.